# Scroll to bottom of C# DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I'm trying to scroll to bottom of a DataGridView in a C# WinForm.

This code works with a TextBox:

```
textbox_txt.SelectionStart = textbox_txt.Text.Length;
textbox_txt.ScrollToCaret();
```

... but I don't know how to do it with a DataGridView. Any help, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataGridView: Scroll down automatically only if the scroll is at the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263377/datagridview-scroll-down-automatically-only-if-the-scroll-is-at-the-bottom)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

To scroll to bottom of `DataGridView` try this.

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount-1;
```

Comment: Useful, thanks.
If your DataGridView has hidden rows then you need to check row visibility because the DataGridView does not let you scroll to invisible rows.

Comment: Good one! If your DataGridView is bound to a BindingSource, you can achieve the same result with dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = BindingSource.Count-1;

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a currently selected cell because the DataGridView tries to keep that cell visible.  Is there any way to force the scroll anyway?  I don't want to change the current cell, just let it scroll off the screen.

Answer (score 6):

As a commercial programmer, I use a C# DLL to handle all my DataGridView projects which gives me language freedom for whatever project I undertake. All of my programs trap all key-presses so that I can use them for my own purposes. For DataGridView scrolling, I use the PageUp/PageDown keys for a single page, Ctrl/Page for single line and Alt/Page for top (Up) and bottom (Down). C# code and Basic calling sequence as follows:

```
//---------- C# Dll Partial Source -----------

public int RowShow
   { get { return vu.DisplayedRowCount(false); } }

public int RowCount 
   { get { return vu.RowCount; } }

public void PageMove(int rows)
{
    int rowlimit = vu.RowCount - 1;
    int calc = vu.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + rows;

    if (calc > rowlimit) calc = rowlimit;  // Go to bottom
    if (calc < 0)        calc = 0;         // Go to top

    vu.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = calc;
}

// ---------- End Data Grid View ----------



//---------- Calling Program C# ----------

public void Page_Key(int val, int lastKey)
{
    int inc = 1;                // vu is DataGridView

    If (val == 33) inc = -1;

    int rowsDisp = vu.RowShow;  // # of rows displayed
    int rowsMax  = vu.RowCount; // # of rows in view
    int rows     = 0;

    switch (lastKey)
    {        
      case 17:                  // Ctrl prior to Page
        rows = inc;
        break; 
      case 19:                  // Alt prior to Page
        rows = rowsMax * inc;
        break;
      default:
        rows = rowsDisp * inc
        break;
    }  // end switch

  vu.PageMove(rows)
} // end Page_Key



'----- Calling Program B4PPC, VB -----

Sub Page_Key(val,lastKey)     ' 33=PageUp, 34=Down
    inc = 1                   ' vu is DataGridView

    If val = 33 then inc = -1

    rowsDisp = vu.RowShow     ' # of rows displayed
    rowsMax  = vu.RowCount    ' # of rows in view
    rows     = 0

    Select lastKey
      Case 17                 ' Ctrl prior to Page
        rows = inc 
      Case 19                 ' Alt prior to Page
        rows = rowsMax * inc
      Case Else
        rows = rowsDisp * inc
    End Select

    lastKey = ""

    vu.PageMove(rows)
End Sub
```