# Scroll goes bottom, but content keeps at top

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I am working with an own extended `System.Windows.Forms.Datagrid`... problem is that when rows are appended, the control does not scroll bottom correctly.

Here is the snippet I use:

```
if (filasAInsertar.Length > 0)
{
    int row_count = niceDataGridDesvios.getVisibleRowsCount(niceDataGridDesvios.Parent) - 1;
    ExtendedDataGrid extendedDataGrid = niceDataGridDesvios.dataGrid;
    extendedDataGrid.getScrollBar().Value = extendedDataGrid.getScrollBar().Maximum;
    niceDataGridDesvios.dataGrid.selectFullRow(row_count);
}
```

This code makes the scrollbar run bottom, but content keeps on top.... Any idea on how to make it well? Already tried to `.performLayout()` and `.Refresh()`, got same results.

Hope you guys could help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of C# DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969061/scroll-to-bottom-of-c-sharp-datagridview)

Comment: @Taegost It seems the OP wants the  code for `DataGrid` not `DataGridView`, I made the same mistake in my first answer. To see how to perform it for `DataGrid` you can take a look at my answer. Hope you find it helpful :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei - Ah yes, I see it now...  When I did the search I missed that little bit of difference, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DataGrid

To set the current row of a [`System.WindowsForms.DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) and scroll to the row you can use [`CurrentRowIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.currentrowindex(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
datGrid1.CurrentRowIndex = 50;
```

For example to scroll to the last row:

```
datGrid1.CurrentRowIndex = d.BindingContext[datGrid1.DataSource].Count - 1;
```

### DataGridView

**CurrentCell**

If you set the [`CurrentCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell(v=vs.110).aspx) of `DataGridView` it selects the specified cell and scrolls to make the cell visible.

For example to select the last row and scroll to it:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[this.dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0];
```

**FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex**

You can also set [`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex(v=vs.110).aspx) to scroll to a specific row, but it doesn't select the row:

For example to only scroll to the last row:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.RowCount-1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Reza, the first one solved my problem.